# bash hangs dealing with output of variable

Tags: bash, nagios, freeze

I wrote a script in bash for reading the values of a XML file from a sensor,
my old script worked like a charm but now I need to give the script the IP of the server via argument.

Here's the problem:
My script works only to a certain point and than hangs, doing nothing(?)

The script is used like the following example:

./script.sh -temp 20 10 192.168.0.4

(-temp is for reading the temperature value, 20 is for an alert if it drops under it, 10 is for an strong alert if it drops under it and 192.168.0.4 is the IP (it will be resolved in combine_host() to -> http://192.168.0.4/details.xml))

I even added some echo to output every needed value in some steps for debugging.
It stops right by

```
    case "$1" in
        -temp)
        echo $host
                pre_testing=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host | sed -n 's:.*    <Temperature Units="Centigrade">\(.*\)</Temperature>.*:\1:p')
        echo $pre_testing
```

So the echo $host is working and outputting the correct address but echo $pre_testing is never running because it hangs in the function above

I really don't know why, just tested so much thinks like outputting it to an other variable, backslashes, etc.
but nothing seems to work

Does someone have an idea?

and yes, the script is working and doing it's job, so I really don't want to rewrite much ;)

Here's the whole source code with my german comments

```
#! /bin/bash

#Syntax:
#script.sh -x1 x2 x3 x4
#-x1 = Wert
#x2 = unter x Warnung
#x3 = unter x kritisch
#x4 = IP des Sensor-Servers
#folgende Werte sind abfragbar:
#-health
#-temp
#-humidity
#-baromb
#-light


#Adresse des WiFi-Sensor-Servers
http="http://"
pre_host=$4
details="/details.xml"
combine_host() { echo $http$pre_host$details; }
host="$( combine_host )"

echo $host

#Argumente abfragen und Daten laden
case "$1" in
        -health)
                testing=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host | sed -n 's:.*    <Health>\(.*\)</Health>.*:\1:p')
            ;;
        -temp)
        echo $host
                pre_testing=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host | sed -n 's:.*    <Temperature Units="Centigrade">\(.*\)</Temperature>.*:\1:p')
        echo $pre_testing
            testing=$(echo $pre_testing | sed -r "s/([^\.]*)\..*/\1/")
        echo $testing
            ;;
        -humidity)
                pre_testing=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host | sed -n 's:.*<Humidity Units="PercentRelativeHumidity">\(.*\)</Humidity>.*:\1:p')
                testing=$(echo $pre_testing | sed -r "s/([^\.]*)\..*/\1/")
            ;;
        -baromb)
                pre_testing=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host | sed -n 's:.*<BarometricPressureMb Units="Millibars">\(.*\)</BarometricPressureMb>.*:\1:p')
                testing=$(echo $pre_testing | sed -r "s/([^\.]*)\..*/\1/")
            ;;
        -light)
                testing=$(wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host | sed -n 's:.*<Light Units="Lux">\(.*\)</Light>.*:\1:p')
            ;;
        -*) echo "Falsches Argument!"
            ;;
    *) echo "kein Argument vorhanden!"
            ;;
esac


#Werte prüfen und ausgeben
if [ $# -ne "3" ];
        then
        status=3
        statustxt=UNKNOWN
        echo "Fehler in der Anfrage!"
        exit 3
elif [ "$testing" -gt "$3" ];
        then
        status=2
        statustxt=CRITICAL
        echo "$status - Sofort Handeln! - Wert_$1 $testing;$2;$3; $statustxt     | '$1'=$testing;$2;$3;;"
        exit 2
elif [ "$testing" -gt "$2" ];
        then
        status=1
        statustxt=WARNING
        echo "$status - Bald Handeln! - Wert_$1 $testing;$2;$3; $statustxt |     '$1'=$testing;$2;$3;;"
        exit 1
else
        status=0
        statustxt=OK
        echo "$status - Alles OK! - Wert_$1 $testing;$2;$3; $statustxt |     '$1'=$testing;$2;$3;;"
        exit 0
fi

done
```

Comment: That is strange, because before I changed the IP thingy it worked like a charm

Comment: "-O" is writing to a file but "-O -" is writing to stdout and "-o" is for writing the log output somewhere else, in my case to /dev/null

Comment: now I only use  `pre_testing=$(wget -O - -o - $host) echo $pre_testing`
even this is not working

Comment: I have to store the output of the whole XML file to a variable, because I don't have writing permission in this folder

Comment: But when you do just `wget -O - -o - $host` can you see data continuously showing on screen ? or not ?

Comment: @Pac0 I'm so dumb xD I had a typo in the IP, I had to give it 192.168.0.5 and not 192.168.0.4, just typed the wrong number :/ My code is working now as it should xD

Comment: ok, so wget was just hanging waiting for a response and never ended. Gladyou solved your problem.

Comment: yes ^^ thank you for your time and efford, have a nice day =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see the problem...
Maybe you are calling it with the wrong arguments?
What's the output of `wget -O - -o /dev/null  $host`?

PS: Grüsse aus der Schweiz :)

Comment: Yes, I had a typo in my arguments ;)

P.S. Grüße aus Norddeutschland ;)